# react native development build working, but release apk crashes after login

Tags: react-native

I am using react native version 0.61.5 My application works fine in development build but when i create a release (signed) apk, it crashes after login. I have already created a logcat file, in logcat it shows error

```
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.reactnativestarter, PID: 24977
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes, stack:
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime: anonymous (address at@1:479896
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime: apply@-1
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime: value (address at@1:81355
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime: apply@-1
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime: value (address at@1:76764
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime: anonymous (address at@1:75185
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime: value (address at@1:76361
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime: value (address at@1:75143
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime: 
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:71)
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:371)
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:150)
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:26)
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:225)
04-24 20:13:26.448 24977 25054 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

already tried to set this false `def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false` but didn't work.
I also tried to disable Hermes but didn't work. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

probably you have an error in that component please recheck your login